# ClipOval vs CircleAvatar

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, user-experience

I'm new to Flutter and when I decided to build a user profile picture widget I found two widgets to make it circular: the `ClipOval` and `CircleAvatar`
So what's the difference between them and when should I use each?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'**ClipOval**' is a widget that clips its child using an oval. you can use this in anywhere of your application, But '**CircleAvatar**' is the best choice for circle that represents a user.
You can use 'CircleAvatar' to used with a user's profile image, or in the absence of such an image, the user's initials.

[More at here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/CircleAvatar-class.html)

Answer (score 1):

`CircleAvatar` is just which is designed to make avatar Widget and similar. `ClipOval` is used to cut the outgoing part of a widget which you want to design as a circle, same as `ClipRRect` for example.
Though, from an appearance point of view, they give the same effect.